# Dynamically allocated array inside std::list leads to memoy leaks

Tags: c++, arrays, list, memory-leaks, std

The following code leads to a memory leakage:

```
  std::list<float*> vertices; 

  float* v;
  for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
      v = new float[3];
      v[0] = v[1] = v[2] = 13;

      vertices.push_back(v);
  }

  std::list<float*>::iterator curr;
  for(curr = vertices.begin(); curr != vertices.end(); curr++) {
      delete[] *curr;
  }

  vertices.clear();
```

I have no idea why it is happening, but I guess it is connected to some anomaly of std::list. 
The weirder part is that if I run the code more than once consequentially, the amount of leaked memory does not change. Can it be that I miss something really basic? 
Can anyone suggest a reason for this? Can I solve this with only changing destruction part of the code?

**More info:**
This is an mfc application. The code is executed on a button press. Before I press the button I see 15mb in the task manager. After I press the button I see 40mb. The button does nothing but executing this code.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak here?

Comment: How much memory is being leaked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mis-interpreting your results. The "leak" you are seeing is not actually a leak, but pre-allocation, which is basically where the CRT or STL keeps around allocated memory incase you need it again for faster allocation time.

Moreover, you should really, really use self-releasing pointers. They're guaranteed never to leak memory, if they're used properly, and there's a wealth of well-written smart pointers in Boost or a new compiler's Standard library.

Edit: Task manager is NOT a reliable way to measure allocations/deallocations/etc. This doesn't even allocate 25MB.

More edit: You wouldn't even need to check if you used proper RAII pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Is there a way to turn this off? I want to be able to distinguish this "cache" from a real memory leaks. I want to see if this was the problem in my real code, or maybe I have another, real leak there (what I showed here is only what I though to be the "dill-down" of the problem).

Comment: @Artium: You typically use code that overrides the default memory allocator with a tracking one. It's easy to use in the STL at least. You shouldn't turn it off because it improves performance hugely. Edit: Or rather, you should use an actual memory profiler, not task manager.

Answer (score 3):

Can't see any memory leak in your code...

You really should use RAII, and you wouldn't need to worry about it... and I would guess that std::vector could be a better choice here since you probably want continuous memory...

e.g.

```
typedef std::array<float, 3> vec3;
std::vector<vec3> vertices; 

for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
    vec3 v = {13, 13, 13};
    vertices.push_back(v);
}  

vertices.clear();
```